# Set MySQL config data on install PHP

Tags: php, mysql, installscript

I've made an install script for mysql tables. I want the user to set the database configurations. The configurations for mysql is hard coded in a PHP class as public variables.

What would be best practice for creating and storing the config data on install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP fwrite() to create content to an empty PHP-file. Content is defined constants of users input. Use these constants to set value to the Database configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a .ini file. Example:

database.config.ini:

```
host = "localhost"
db = "test"
user = "root"
pass = ""
```

To load config:

```
$config = parse_ini_file('database.config.ini');
print_r($config);

/*Array
(
    [host] => "localhost"
    [db] => "test"
    [user] => "root"
    [pass] => ""
)*/
```

Comment: @Zlatan I do not understand your question. For details on the function you can read the php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: is it readable if I access to an .ini file from my browser man?

Comment: @Zlatan Yes, the browser interprets as text/plain.

Comment: You can deny access from this file extension via .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Create a form for accept config data, during the process these content to write to a file or a xml . Then read from file config datas

Comment: Is it possible to write to the PHP file instead? XML doesn't sound that safe for storing that kind of data.

Comment: Thats i am not sure,please try